# Not seeing database from localhost but seeing it when connecting to server

Tags: mysql, database-administration

I'm connecting to the mysql server as user '`someuser`'. When I connect to the server from my localbox I get to see all the databases.

However, when I SSH into the server and login with '`someuser`' and execute `show databases;` I only see two: `information_schema` and `test`

How can I view all the databases when I SSH into the DB as well?

`show grants;` shows the below

```
mysql> show grants;
| Grants for dev@localhost                                             |
 | GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'someuser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*' |
```

Edit

When I SSH into the server and login to mysql using root then I can see all the databases fine.

Comment: can't u see database named `mysql` ? And what do u mean by "localbox"?

Comment: how many instances of mysql is running?  Are you sure you have connected to the same instance in both cases?

Comment: hmm to my knowledge I'm only running one.

Comment: @Manu by localbox I mean my localmachine using which I connect to the server.

Comment: @Omnipresent.. That machine is not showing you `mysql` database?

Comment: no. it only shows `information_schema` and `test` when I execute `show databases;`

Comment: @Slowcoder I run `mysql -u someuser -p` on the server and when on localbox I am connecting to it using the ip address of the server and port 3306

Comment: did you try connecting to one of the databases using "mysql -u username -p your_database" in SSH?

Comment: I had not tried that. Just tried it now and no. It says Access Denied for the databases I can't see. However, it works fine for `test` database which I can see from `show databases;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GRANT USAGE is not what you want. According to the mysql documentation:

```
USAGE   Synonym for “no privileges”
```

It is used at the global level with GRANT to modify account attributes such as resource limits or SSL characteristics without affecting existing account privileges.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/grant.html

You need to grant actual privileges to your "someuser" user for the database the user needs to see. For example, if you grant select privileges on the mysql.*:

```
GRANT SELECT ON mysql.* 
TO someuser@localhost IDENTIFIED BY "somepassword";
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Now, someuser connected from localhost will be able to see the mysql database when executing

```
SHOW DATABASES;
```

However, you might want to reserve the access to the mysql database for root only.